# Room database pre-populate database with different languages

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-room

I am using Room database in my app and I am using 4 different languages. I translated all texts with Translation Editor. I prepopulated some texts to database from string resource file. The problem is when I change the language in the app, it doesn't update the current texts to that language in Room db. What should I do ?

Comment: Use String Resource and a global language and then use a BaseActivity to manage preferences according to user

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already use String resource

Comment: See how [these](https://github.com/tachiyomiorg/tachiyomi/blob/03980b2f27bc80bc578808f86a1e114a72a3559e/app/src/main/java/eu/kanade/tachiyomi/util/system/LocaleHelper.kt) [guys](https://github.com/tachiyomiorg/tachiyomi/blob/99b46096a46ce4a56f4461d7ad7c7a24b0cf510b/app/src/main/java/eu/kanade/tachiyomi/ui/browse/source/LangHolder.kt) did.